# Google Map doesn't zoom out very much

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I have this map (supportMapFragment) and it doesn't zoom out more than this.
I remember that sometime ago I was able to zoom out till see the whole planisphere, but now I can't even see a continent!

[image]

The only thing I've changed is to use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment (because it's inserted in a SlidingPaneLayout, that wants support fragments). It's possibile that support map isn't able to zoom out more than this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is by design you cannot see the whole map, but it was already requested on [gmaps-api-issues -> issue 5724](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5724) to support this. Star it to give it a higher priority.

I have a feeling that the above issue is blocked by [another issue reported there](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5285).

From my observations there is no difference between `SupportMapFragment` and `MapFragment` when it comes to min zoom level. One thing that matters is device's screen size (or more specifically fragment's size).
From your screenshot I can see zoom level 3. If you want to be able to zoom out to 2, you have to make your fragment a bit smaller. Try adding 50dp margins as a test.

Comment: Oh, this is possible, but I was saying that sometime ago (when I used mapFragment) I could see much more map than now (I'm using supportMapFragment). I don't know if the problem is that, and I can't try using mapFragment again because the map is in a SlindinPaneLayout.

Comment: @lore_barba I've updated the answer with links and more explanations of current limitations.

Answer (score -1):

Based on documentation,

The desired zoom level, in the range of 2.0 to 21.0. Values below this range are set to 2.0, and values above it are set to 21.0. Increase the value to zoom in. 
Not all areas have tiles at the largest zoom levels.

```
 Googlemap gm;
 LatLng cur_Latlng = new LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000);
 gm.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(cur_Latlng));
 gm.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10)); 
     gm.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

You can increase level from 2.0 to 21.0

Comment: this isn't the answer to my question, I'm able to zoom in and out, the problem is that it doesn't zoom out more than that!